# OpenCV classification in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-services, opencv, neural-network, backend

I am building my own NodeJS server and I want to use OpenCV in order to make an image recognition service of my server. In order to do that I've followed the first part of this guide (I don't need to use COCO SSD).

https://medium.com/@muehler.v/node-js-meets-opencvs-deep-neural-networks-fun-with-tensorflow-and-caffe-ff8d52a0f072

The problem is that when I run the classification of a certain image, for example the banana example reported in the guide, what I got is a meaningless integer value plus the accuracy of the prediction, instead of getting the name of the object plus the accuracy.

For example I get

```
32 (0.96)
```

instead of getting

```
banana (0.96)
```

How can I solve that?